# How can I make my progress meter synchronize better?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, progress-bar

I've made a file upload progress meter that counts up to 100 but it seems to do it too fast. There is significant wait time after it completes to 100. How can Iimprove it so that the count is more synchronized with the upload?

```
   <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
$(function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        url: 'http://www.koolbusiness.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ZMljyzbg9uayiMv3bOYEVbRkaopfu-ha7I6hHb-FgXpkiXiNuSDRxceyEpzz0q5g4IZt440neSvxI1ePcwP_5shOlqJ164XUJTc0M1XJwjvZbk1RY7QY7cTMmPrco6F3qRBf0O/ALBNUaYAAAAAVakVSot1IKu5WdT3sVltkiWsmS4F2rGn/',
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
           $('#wrapper').html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Are you using a plugin?

Comment: @RyanNeuffer yes, I'm using the jquery form plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra time, is the time it takes the server to process your request. If you make the server return faster, you will have less wait time after 100%. A client can't make a progress bar, for the server side part of it, as it have no idea how long it's going to take. Your progress bar only count as long as it's uploading data.

Perhaps you can do some async handling on the server and then return faster? You can also make it so that the server can tell the progress of processing your request and calculate that into the bar.